# Are "The laptop display shows a message." and "The laptop displays a message." equal in meaning?

Tags: grammaticality

Are "The laptop display shows a message." and "The laptop displays a message." equal in meaning? (And grammatically correct.)

Answer (score 1):

They are both grammatical, but not quite equal in meaning because *display* in the first one is a noun, standing for the laptop's screen. In the second one, *displays* is a verb, performing the same role as *shows* in the first one. The second sentence thus, strictly speaking, conveys less information than the first one, because it does not specify that the laptop shows the message on its own screen. However, because the laptops can normally be presumed to show messages on their own screens (to display [verb] them on their own displays [noun]), the two sentences are interchangeable for most real-life purposes.

Comment: That's true. The laptop could have an external monitor.

Comment: The laptop could have a sticker that displays a message as well.